# How to manage android text size?

Tags: android, textview, android-fonts, text-size, android-textattributes

Take this textview snippet for example:

```html
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTotal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
        app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        app:lineHeight="60dp"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="2.5"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="6dp" />
```

I have `android:textSize="30sp"`, `app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"`, and `app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"` all set. Whenever I changed the `android:textSize`, it seems to have no effect on my phone. Why is this? Also, does `app:lineHeight` have any effect when `android:lineSpacingMultiplier` and `android:lineSpacingExtra` are set? What do these properties even do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove `app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"`, that time your code is work. 
Because when you use `app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"`, that time `android:textSize="30sp"`does not work.

The difference is that `android:lineSpacingExtra` add extra spacing between lines of text of TextView and `android:lineSpacingMultiplier` work as scale factor for height of line space. in other words, each line height will be `height*multiplier + extra`

Comment: I accepted it. Also, can you see my updated question above?

Comment: @shikhar-mainalee Thanks..Now I updated the answer. May help this for you.